# Output from parsing an XML file isn't the same as hard coding a string into an re

Tags: regex, xml, python-2.7

I am parsing an OpenStreetMaps XML file and reformatting phone numbers to the standard +1 123 456 7890. I've created regular expressions for all the bad formats and have created a function to clean them up:

```
def fix_phone(phone_list):
    bad_format = re.compile(r'(\W\d\s)(\W\d{3}\W\s)(\d{3}\W\d{4}$)')
    for phone in phone_list:
        if bad_format.search(phone):
            phone = phone[0:2]+" "+phone[4:7]+" "+phone[9:12]+" "+phone[13:]
```

For the phone number `'+1 (720) 406-9696'`, this function is giving me this result back: `'+1 1 ( 0)  06-9696'`

How is this happening? If I type these three lines of code into a new jupyter cell:

```
phone = '+1 (720) 406-9696'
if re.compile(r'(\W\d\s)(\W\d{3}\W\s)(\d{3}\W\d{4}$)').search(phone):
    print phone[0:2]+" "+phone[4:7]+" "+phone[9:12]+" "+phone[13:]
```

I get the desired result `'+1 720 406 9696'`. What am I missing?

Comment: The actual match results are `**  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 17 ) 
+1 (720) 406-9696  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 : len 3 ) 
+1   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 3 : len 6 ) 
(720)   
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 9 : len 8 ) 
406-9696`  You should format based on that.

Comment: Can you please explain how my format does not go along with the match results?  From my understanding, 

`+1` == `phone[0:2]`  

`720` == `phone[4:7]`  

`406` == `phone[9:12]`  

`9696` == `phone[13:]`

Comment: Why not just print the capture groups? Change the regex to `(\W\d)\s\W(\d{3})\W\s(\d{3})\W(\d{4})$` and print out the 4 groups.

Comment: Are you aware, even if your activities are solely confined to the United States, that there are phone numbers that don't fit this format, for example visitors from overseas whose mobile phones are registered in a different country? Are you deliberately trying to exclude such people?